# struct within a struct program won't start

Tags: c

I was trying to make a struct within a struct program that will locate a house and measure it's built time and it's area.

I am getting this error.

[Error] 'izgradnja' has no member named 'povrsina'

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct {
    char drzava[30];
    char grad[30];
    char adresa[50];
    char tip[10];
    int brojsoba;
    int brojradnika;
    struct povrsina {
    int sirina;
    int duzina;
    int povrsinasobe;
};
}izgradnja;
main() {
    int i,n,j;
    printf("Koliko objekata cemo obraditi:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    izgradnja objekat[n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("Unesite drzavu u kojoj je Vasa kuca:");
        gets(objekat[i].drzava);
        printf("Unesite grad u kojoj je Vasa kuca:");
        gets(objekat[i].grad);
        printf("Unesite adresu:");
        gets(objekat[i].adresa);
        printf("Da li gradite kucu ili stan:");
        gets(objekat[i].tip);
        printf("Koliko ima soba?");
        scanf("%d",&objekat[i].brojsoba);
        for(j=0;j<objekat[i].brojsoba;j++) {
            printf("Unesite sirinu i duzinu:");
            scanf("%d%d",&objekat[i].povrsina.sirina,&objekat[i].povrsina.duzina);
            objekat[i].povrsina.povrsinasobe = objekat[i].povrsina.sirina * objekat[i].povrsina.duzina;
        }
        printf("Unesite broj radnika koji radi na kuci:");
        scanf("%d",&objekat[i].brojradnika);
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is only started.
I'll add printf after I find where is the error.

Comment: Keep in mind that your question should be complete when you post it here. If it's not, don't post the question. There's no penalty for keeping it open in a browser tab while you're finishing it.

Comment: It is indeed finished the question, I had a problem with how to finish this starting phase.

A friendly member of the community helped me. I just added this comment if someone is confused why program is not finished.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several ways to solve it, but this should work:

```
typedef struct {
    char drzava[30];
    char grad[30];
    char adresa[50];
    char tip[10];
    int brojsoba;
    int brojradnika;

    struct {
        int sirina;
        int duzina;
        int povrsinasobe;
    } povrsina;

} izgradnja;
```

Or just split it up:

```
typedef struct {
    int sirina;
    int duzina;
    int povrsinasobe;
} Povrsina;

typedef struct {
    char drzava[30];
    char grad[30];
    char adresa[50];
    char tip[10];
    int brojsoba;
    int brojradnika;
    Povrsina povrsina;
} izgradnja;
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, it works now.

Thanks.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it worked for you.